# How to show backdrop on top of backdrop with modals in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

In my application i have a modal which open an other modal.

In both modal i want to show backdrop (black background). On the first modal Backdrop is working perfectly, but on the second one backdrop doesnt show up even that page/UI behinde modal is disabled.

Any ideas what can cause such problem? i have basicly exactly same code for those 2 modals.

```
var modalOpened = false;
$scope.$on('myEvent', function(event, data) {
            //prevent modal to open twice
    if(modalOpened) return;

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        backdrop: 'static',
        templateUrl: 'myTemplate',
        controller: controller,
        keyboard : false
    }); 
    modalOpened = true;

    modalInstance.result.then(function(message) {
        modalOpened = false;
    }, function() {});
});
```

Howerver if i alow modal to opne up twice, backdrop is shown. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You need to close the previous modal, wait for few milliseconds and then open the second modal (use `$timeout` to call second modal after few milliseconds) - See if that does the trick.

Comment: i thought about it, but i need to have both of them up at the sametime

Comment: Then you are not making use of modals properly. Two modals opened at the same time is not a good idea.

Comment: what can i use instead to show a progressbar on top of modal an lock backgoround at the same time?

Comment: Why can't you show progress bar in the modal itself? I mean in the first modal at the bottom of the modal or something like that? It's a design choice so its left up to you... Either show one modal at a time or show information of both modals in a single modal

Comment: Ehm, i think i found a bug in bootstrap-UI, when they count z-index of more then 1 modal they are always 10 behinde.